# Why am I able to use this variable in the other event

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding variable scope. I declared de variable `BMI` outside the event blocks but then attributed a value to it inside the MouseCLick event of the `calculate` button. Why am I able to use the BMI variable in the `classify` button's event with the calculation value? I thought the value I had changed it to was local and could only be used inside that event.

```
    int age;
    double weight, height, BMI;

    private void bt_calculate_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        if (int.TryParse(txt_age.Text, out age) && double.TryParse(txt_weight.Text, out weight) && double.TryParse(txt_height.Text, out height)
            && age > 0 && weight > 0 && height > 0)

        {
            BMI = weight / (height * height);


            if (age >= 20)
            {
                txt_calculate.Text = Convert.ToString(BMI);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Take a look at picture 1.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide valid values.");
        }
    }

    private void bt_classify_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        if (BMI <= 18.5)
        {
            txt_classify.Text = "Underweight";
        }
        else if (BMI > 18.5 && BMI <= 24.9)
        {
            txt_classify.Text = "Normal Weight";
        }
        else
        {
            txt_classify.Text = "Overweight";
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's a *field*, not a *variable*

Comment: if you had passed the value to the function you would be correct, but it seems like its a global variable(at class level) which means this variable is accessible from the calls blocks and all he's subfunctions

Comment: Tip: A [_minimal_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example would be better. We don't really need to be quibbling in perpetuity about changes in BMI ranges proposed by various medical authorities.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared your fields at the class level, meaning they are accessible from all scope blocks (`{ ... }`) within the class scope (including method scopes and nested scopes).

In short: variables, fields, methods, etc. declared in a scope are available in all child scopes of that scope. The reverse is not true: you can't declare a variable in a method and then access it from the class level.

So consider this example:

```
class Test
{
    int myVariable = 5;

    void TestA()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                ++myVariable; // this works, we can see myVariable
            }
        }
    }

    void TestB()
    {
        --myVariable; // this also works
    }
}
```

Within the class scope, we have a method scope for the `void Test()` method, and then we create a scope with the `if` statement, and within that we create a further-nested scope with the `while` loop. Because `myVariable` was declared in a less-nested scope, you can still access it.

If we defined it like this:

```
class Test
{
    void TestA()
    {
        int myVariable = 5;
    }

    void TestB()
    {
        // can't see MyVariable because it's in a different scope, and that scope isn't above the current scope
    }

    void TestC()
    {
        {
            int myOtherVariable = 5;
        }
        // can't see myOtherVariable because it was defined in a child scope of this method scope
    }
}
```

Note that whichever method you reference the class field/property from, you are still accessing the same data in memory. Note that this works differently when you pass the variable as an argument, and depends on if it's a value type or a reference type.

See [this article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx) for more information about scopes.

Comment: I understand the fact the I can access the variable because I declared it outside, what I don't understand is how changing the value inside the event block causes it to change outside the block. Isn't it what is happening? So I guess my question would be whether changing a value inside one block causes it to change globally inside the class.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you change it from, you're still referencing the same block of memory.

Comment: @SpencerHastings, it is not a variable, but a (instance) field. You might call it "instance variable", though. It is associated with and exists within the object instance it belongs to. It is NOT associated and does NOT belong to a method scope. Scopes of methods don't matter with regard to lifetime and accessiblity of fields. If you change the value of a field, you change the value of this field. Whether the change of a field happens "Outside"/"inside"/"whateverside" of some method doesn't matter a bit...